# xflock4 (lock screen) will shutdown

Tags: xfce, xubuntu

I have a fresh Xubuntu 18.04 installed (XFCE desktop enviroment). On Lenovo ThinkPad 480 i7. Everything works well just one issue:

for some reason when I lock screen with `xflock4` ( default shortcut `alt+ctr+l` ) instead of screen lock the laptop will shut down

it happens even if I execute `xflock4` from terminal

Comment: Are you sure it was shutdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=11726

`which xflock4 # => /usr/bin/xflock4`

inside this file:

```
for lock_cmd in \
    "xscreensaver-command -lock" \
    "light-locker-command --lock" \
    "gnome-screensaver-command --lock"
do
    $lock_cmd >/dev/null 2>&1 && exit
done
```

so I don't have `xscreensaver-command` installed but I do have  `light-locker-command`

​

so I'm 100% sure the `light-locker-command --lock` is causing this as when I trigger it from terminal same thing happen (screen goes blank, and  freezes, shutdown is only option)

​

I tried to install `xscreensaver-command`  => `sudo apt install xscreensaver`

​

so now if I do `xscreensaver-command -lock` the lock works great

​

as the `xscreensaver-command -lock`  it is first command in the `xflock4`  it will take precedence over the broken light-locker-command and problem solved

​

> you may get `xscreensaver-command: no screensaver is running on display :0.0` after instalation. this just means the daemon for this screansaver applicatino is not running. All you need to do is go to `Menu> Screansaver` and when asked 'No daemon running, do you want to lunch it' say yes

​

​

Solved my issue ;)

cross post https://www.reddit.com/r/xubuntu/comments/boxfmq/xflock4_lock_screen_will_shutdown/